# How do I find out what camera was used to take this photo?

Tags: image-quality, nikon-d3200

I want a way to know what camera produced this beautiful photo. I shot a photo in the same place with my Nikon D3200, but it was not close to the quality of the other shots.  I believe that could be an iPhone camera for the contrast in the images, but I am not sure.

[Camera X image](https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17991377_1955376028017323_6681653899496350472_o.jpg?oh=b23b2ebf51d8440d6982410cf8d685c8&oe=5982E54E)[image]

[My Nikon D3200 shot](https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17807506_1260165867394706_8751240563954105437_o.jpg?oh=eb80ca971bed34d3fc325f2043e1fdd5&oe=5989D8BC)[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific about what aspects of the photo you'd like to emulate most. What do you think makes it beautiful? The camera used to take the shots is almost completely irrelevant. You could easily take a more beautiful photo with your Nikon.

Comment: @HarryHarrison You need to be more specific about what aspects of the photo he could easily take on his Nikon would be more beautiful.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th That's funny! I wrote an answer that addressed pretty much the same thing and it got downvoted at almost the identical time that you made your comment. Hmmm...

Comment: @MichaelClark I just found it funny that the commenter asked for clarification about OP's definition of beauty - and then went ahead and assumed we'd know what his definition was.  Like most of my comments - not particularly helpful to anyone.  I haven't read any of the answers, but I'm sorry to hear about your downvote.

Comment: Copy cats are never nice to smell xDD
Just go, try by yourself and learn. Best way to learn photography. And of course checking work you like but not copying, just getting the idea of what you'd like to achieve and then do it your way.

Answer (score 6):

Normally one looks ar EXIF information to see which camera make and model took a photo. There is also *almost* always information regarding the lens used too. If you use legacy lenses or an adapter it is unlikely the information is there though.

What you linked to is not a photo, it's a composite image and might even be made with images from different cameras. Even if the same camera was used, it could be still different lenses. Unless you got something closer to the source, there is no sure way to know.

That being said, if your Nikon D3200 is not giving you a good shot, there are a lot of things to blame before the camera. The main difference you show is the light. I would say it makes all the difference here. You shot on an overcast day, their top shot is shot under sunny conditions. The bottom to shots are also taken on overcast days, in which case it could be the lens or simply your configuration. By default many DSLRs like the D3200 have somewhat soft and and low contrast tonality. You should adjust setting to your liking, it is in the camera menu under *Picture Control*. A good lens makes very good difference in terms of sharpness, contrast and flare.

Comment: I would not blame the camera at all :o( Poor camera.

Answer (score 4):

The bad news is, and I do not mean to be rude, there is a little problem with  the device holding the camera. Xo)

The image you linked as an example has nothing special in terms of light. (On a landscape you have to live with what you have, unless you can spend some days returning to that location in different weather conditions and hours of the day)

#### Compose the image

But it has a decent framing, and that is all about two things:

1. Move around and **see**.
2. When you are on an interesting spot, move the camera **and frame**.

I do not know if you gave up taking just one shot of what was in front of you or you put some effort to move around watching the surroundings.

Your photo has no point of interest, has no composition, you need to work on that. Move, take a photo laying down, move one step to the left or to the right, force a perspective, take different planes at the same time... COMPOSE the image.

Here is a post about composition: [My attention gets repeatedly distracted by the elements needed for the context in this picture. Where am I going wrong?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64966/my-attention-gets-repeatedly-distracted-by-the-elements-needed-for-the-context-i) Explore that tag on this site. https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition

#### Remove the people

Take several shots, using a tripod, across several minutes and then use the "no people" zones to composite a clean image.

---

Regarding the camera taking the other images... It really does not matter. In Youtube there is a really funny "Pro Photographer, Cheap Camera Challenge" of a DigitalRev channel

Look for example this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uv0n52-ncmg&t=934s

Answer (score 1):

Light and composition. Light and composition. Light and composition.

The specific camera used has nothing to do with how well the photographer uses existing light (or creates/shapes their own light) to compose a photograph.

That is all.